# Unable to cast object of type System.String to type System.Decimal

Tags: c#, .net, generics

i am getting type conversion error  what things i a doing wrong here ?

```
    private static T1 StringToDecimal<T1, T2>(T2 dummydata)
    {
        var type = typeof(T1);//string 
        var type2 = typeof(T2);//decimal
        Console.WriteLine("Type of T1 is : " + type);
        Console.WriteLine("Type of T2 is : " + type2);
        return (T1)Convert.ChangeType(dummydata, typeof(T2), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        //System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Decimal'.'

        //calling
        //string? _dummydata = "8468.45";
        //var getresult_ = StringToDecimal<string, decimal>(_dummydata);
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAOsO.png

```
Final working code

    private static TToConvertTo StringToDecimal<TToConvertFrom, TToConvertTo>(TToConvertFrom dummydata)
    {
        return (TToConvertTo)Convert.ChangeType(dummydata, typeof(TToConvertTo), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```

Comment: That "calling" you're showing tries to pass in a string as the argument of type `T2`, which you've explicitly specified to be `decimal`. That code won't compile, since "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'decimal'". Please show your actual code and errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've simply mixed up your generic arguments. The conversion is working, but the subsequent cast is failing.

Consider the following correct implementation with updated generic type names that make sit more obvious what is happening:

```
private static TToConvertTo StringToDecimal<TToConvertFrom, TToConvertTo>(
    TToConvertFrom dummydata)
{
    var type = typeof(TToConvertFrom);//string 
    var type2 = typeof(TToConvertTo);//decimal
    Console.WriteLine("Type of T1 is : " + type);
    Console.WriteLine("Type of T2 is : " + type2);

    return (TToConvertTo)Convert.ChangeType(dummydata, type2,
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: OP's supposed "call" doesn't even compile, though, so the whole post is a bit iffy...

Comment: if i replacing type2 with TToConvertTo  then its not working return (TToConvertTo)Convert.ChangeType(dummydata, TToConvertTo, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  why ?

Comment: can i remove  var type2 = typeof(TToConvertTo) statement

Comment: You can't use TToConvertTo directly...it is a compile-time type, whereas the ChangeType method takes a runtime type, expressed as Type. That's why you need `typeof(ToToConvertTo)`.

Comment: @AKX that's absolutely true, although I think it is fairly obvious what their intent was.

Comment: yes i got it i just looked the chnagetype method thanks @DavidL  now my code is working .

Comment: @DavidL Yeah, even if intent might be obvious, it's also obvious that OP can't get the error they claimed to get from the code they had.